# How to resolve Upload to TestRail failed due to a network error

Tags: testrail

I am unable to get a clear reason why this error occurs and the steps I need to resolve it. If I use --insecure still I get an error:- keyError custom_automation_id. Is there any one who resolved this error differently apart from using --insecure.

--insecure
returns custom_automation_id

Comment: I think you might want to add more details about what you are trying to achieve and what you are doing.